# Escribir php en un append de en un js externo

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un js externo que me funciona y me abre el append y todo ok, pero intento meterle php y no encuentro manera de que me funcione. ¿Hay alguna manera de a un append introducir código en php?. He probado con `<?php"+ +"?>`,`<?php". ."?>`,`<?php" "?>`

`$('#campofecha').append("Dia: <input type='date' name='fecha1' value='"<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"' pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' required >");`

Comment: Y que valor muestra ese input #campofecha ?

Comment: En ese caso era la fecha actual, pero la idea es pasarle el valor desde un controlador

Comment: Quieres imprimir una variable con php para usarla dentro de javascript?

Comment: Si, ya que al cargar de nuevo la página y mostrar unos resultados quiero dejar la fecha o fechas que seleccionó en la fecha (para eso uso el append si es solo una fecha le muestro solo un campo fecha y si es un rango de fechas le muestro los dos campos fecha)

Comment: Has intentado cambiar las comillas?

Comment: He probado lo que he puesto arriba al abrir la comilla doble es cuando se supone que puedes poner una variable, si no la reconoce como texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está mal formateado, primero que todo, para los atributos HTML se usan comillas dobles (""):

```
$('#campofecha').append('Dia: <input type="date" name="fecha1" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" required >');
```

Luego, para agregar tu valor desde php, solo añade esto:

```
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"
```

Ya que cuando cargues la página, `<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>` se convertirá en `2019-02-06` y quedará así:

```
value="2019-02-06"
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Justo!! había que abir las comillas simples primero, y en vez de poner en el date con comillas simples, tambien con comillas dobles como todo lo de dentro

$('#campofecha').append('Dia: <input type="date" name="fecha1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" required >');

Comment: Que bueno que te haya funcionado! Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta!

Answer (score 0):

Para que la etiqueta  te funcione, debe estar en un archivo con extensión php. 
Lo que podías hacer es asignar el valor a una variable global en javascript y utilizar esta en tu archivo js.

principal.php

```
<script>
    document.__today = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>';
</script>
```

archivo.js

```
    $('#campofecha').append("Dia: <input type='date' name='fecha1' value='" + document.__today + "' pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' required >");
```

Comment: Al final como ha escrito JCAguilera sólo había que poner bien el formato, ya que como dije el js está en un archivo externo que lo cargo en mi página php